# convert a nested JSON file to a table using D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have `JSON` data similar to the one shown below. I would like to convert the same data into a table using `D3.js` can anyone help me on this?

**JSON Data:**

```
{
    "items": [
        {
        "tableName": "incidents",
        "count": 20000,
        "columnNames": [
            "id",
            "subject",
            "category"
        ],
        "rows": [
            [
                "61",
                "Test",
                null
            ],
            [
                "65",
                "TEST 2",
                null
            ]...
}
```

**Output:**

```
Id Subject Category

61  TEST 1  Null

65  TEST 2  Null
```

Comment: Welcome! Please look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please show your attempt at getting the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data:

```js
var data = {
    "items": [
        {
        "tableName": "incidents",
        "count": 20000,
        "columnNames": [
            "id",
            "subject",
            "category"
        ],
        "rows": [
            [
                "61",
                "Test",
                null
            ],
            [
                "65",
                "TEST 2",
                null
            ],
            [
                "67",
                "TEST 3",
                "not null"
            ]
         ]
     }
  ]
}

function tabulate(data, columns) {
  
  var table = d3.select('body').append('table')
  var thead = table.append('thead')
  var tbody = table.append('tbody');

  // append the header row
  thead.append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
    .data(columns).enter()
    .append('th')
      .text(function (column) { return column; });

  // create a row for each object in the data
  var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data.items[0].rows)
    .enter()
    .append('tr');

  // create a cell in each row for each column
  var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
    .data(function (row,i) {return row; })
    .enter()
    .append('td')
      .text(function (d) { return d; });

   return table;
 }

 // render the table(s)
  tabulate(data, data.items[0].columnNames); // data, columns table
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Source: http://bl.ocks.org/jfreels/6734025